# MATLAB Coder hello world start to finish

Tags: c++, matlab, compilation, makefile, matlab-coder

**Edit**

After going through this much effort only to produce faulty .exe files we have decide to not spend more time trying to generate the code and to instead write it ourselves. Thank you all for your time.

_/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/ _/

**TL;DR question**

I have exported C++ code from MATLAB with MATLAB Coder, how do I compile it?

**Full question**

Using the Matlab App "MATLAB Coder" you can compile MATLAB code to C++ code. I know some of the steps but not all of them, and after some extensive googling I only found pieces of answers and have not succeeded. Let's work together and piece together the information. I intend to structure this question as a guide.

This is the MATLAB program we want as C++ code:

```matlab
disp('Hello World')
```

**0. Rewriting:**

First off, MATLAB Coder needs a function and a .m file running the function. The code was re-written as one file called **HelloWorld.m**

```matlab
function [] = Helloworld()
    disp('Hello World')
end
```

And another file called **ScriptHelloWorld.m**, which contains:

```matlab
HelloWorld();
```

**1. Running MATLAB Coder**

The program is pretty straight forward, once you locate it. It's in "Apps" and then you can choose to start the MATLAB Coder. This is included from MATLAB 2015 and onward. Once started, you select the file you want run, and then you choose the file that runs it. No problems here as they are both very simple files. We decided to name the project "HejWorld".

**2. Getting the files**

This is where information is not so clear anymore. All the files will land in a folder of your choice, and supposedly they are all important. This is what the file structure looks like:

[image: Compiled data file structure]

With the inside of lib looking like this:

[image: Inside of lib folder]

And the inside of mex looking like this:

[image: Inside of mex file]

**3. Compiling**

This is where I'm clueless. It should just be to compile the files but it doesn't prove to be an easy task. I have located [where the makefile is](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36350-matlab-coder-c-code-generated-how-to-compile) in codegen/lib/HelloWorld/HelloWorld_rtw.mk, but there might be more makefiles because I am unsure of what to build.

Also, there is a .prj file located in the root, HelloWorld.prj, as can be seen in the first screenshot. I cannot find a way to run this with gcc or any other application.

Thanks for your help people!

Answer (score 1):

You need all the files under lib/Helloworld. If you invoke the makefile Helloworld_rtw.mk in that directory from your shell it should create a library Helloworld.so in unix platforms and Helloworld.lib on windows.

```
gmake -f Helloworld_rtw.mk build
```

You can link your code against this library to call the main function Helloworld in that library. An example main.c with a call to Helloworld is placed under examples directory. You should be able to compile this example into an executable after adding the Helloworld library as a linker option and include paths for headers.

To see it working instead of calling disp in your code you may want to do some simple arithmetic as below. This is because disp does not generate any code for lib target.

```
function [y] = Helloworld(u)
    y = 2*u;
end
```

In ScriptHellowWorld.m

```
Helloworld(2);
```

You can manually add printf statements in your copy of main function after calling Helloworld function.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not replying earlier. I tried to make in three ways but none work. The one you suggested, gmake, simply gives "command not found", but I read that xcode installs gmake as just make. Running make -f Helloworld_rtw.mk build gives "target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.". I also tried using gcc but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Rkey gmake is installed together with MATLAB:  ie, on my system: `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/gmake`

Comment: There is no MATLAB folder in my /usr/local/ and in /Applications/MATLAB_R_2015b.app/bin/ there is no glnxa64. Could that path be for windows or ubuntu perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to compile the code for the same machine on which you are running MATLAB or one with a compatible architecture, you can just let MATLAB Coder do the compilation for you. Say you want a static library. Then choose that from the `Build Type` dropdown and make sure that `Generate Code Only` is unchecked. See the documentation for a [screenshot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/gs/generating-c-code-from-matlab-code-using-the-matlab-coder-project-interface.html#bsumpws-17).

Once code generation is complete, MATLAB Coder will compile the code to produce a static library in `codegen/lib/Helloworld`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want! However, running this I received an error. The error is "Failed to generate all binary outputs" and the most interesting line I can find in the Build Log is "undefined reference to 'WinMain' ". I'm googling this atm, just letting you know what happened.

Comment: Did you choose "Executable" under "Build type"? If so, the linker is complaining that it can't find a `main` function. For testing, just change the "Build type" to "Static library" or "Dynamic library" and the code will compile. If you would like an executable, you need to specify a C file containing your main function. [This example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/standalone-c-c-executables-from-matlab-code.html#bswnwkz-1) shows how to do that.

Comment: Doing this we arrive at a situation similar to where we started. We get c-code but we have no way to compile it. At least I don't know of a way to compile it.

Comment: If you choose static or dynamic library, MATLAB Coder will compile the C code into such a library for you which you can find in the directory with the code. [http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/using-a-matlab-coder-dynamic-library-in-a-simple-microsoft-visual-studio-project.html](This page) shows how to use the library in Visual Studio. Otherwise, if you follow the [http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/standalone-c-c-executables-from-matlab-code.html#bswnwkz-1](example) I posted above, it will show you how to compile and link an executable.

Comment: We just followed those instructions sep by step, twice. Both times the rand outputted the same value each time. After going through this much effort to create a faulty .exe file we have decided that going further is not worth the effort.